# Adding Extra Fields to Access Token in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 Identity Server and I need to add additional fields to the access token returned from the /oauth2/token endpoint. The current structure of the access token is as follows:

```
{
  "sub": "XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXX",
  "aut": "APPLICATION_USER",
  "aud": "QVwR39k12Fqu",
  "nbf": 1234581515,
  "azp": "WVwR39k12Fqu_YTGKJHNlk",
  "scope": "default",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 153566545,
  "iat": 55585552,
  "jti": "89852_defsdfcsddf",
  "client_id": "Ussswtttt"
}
```

I would like to add extra fields from user information to this token. Is there a configuration or extension point in WSO2 Identity Server that allows me to include additional information in the access token? If so, could you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

**Additional Context:**
WSO2 Identity Server version: 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this done as follows:

1. Hope you have a [local claim](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/dialects/add-claim-mapping/#add-local-claim) for the user attribute.
2. [Add an OIDC claim mapping](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/dialects/add-claim-mapping/#add-external-claim) for your local claim

[image]

3. Go to the created oauth/oidc based service provider -> Claim Configurations-> add the local claim you want in the JWT as a `Requested Claims`
4. Go to `OIDC Scopes` section of - > `List`. Select `openid` scope. Click Add Claims and give the OIDC claim you created in step 2

Now try the token retrieval with `scope=openid`. If the user has a value to the particular claim, you can get it in the JWT access token and ID token